# setViewBox() performance issues on mobile devices

Tags: svg, raphael

On Safari Mobile the use of the `setViewBox()` function from raphaelJS seems to create performance issues. FYI the raphael element drives a predefined svg element within your code.

(RaphaelJS Reference: "Sets the view box of the paper. Practically it gives you ability to zoom and pan whole paper surface by specifying new boundaries."))

While using it on my desktop fluidly, it shows very obvious performance issues on a device like the ipad2.

Can anyone confirm or deny this?